# Advanced Caro Kann: Queenless Middlegame

Tags: analysis, middlegame, caro-kann

I started analysing my games as a means to improvement.

I am trying to form my own opinion without looking at the engine that much, as I can't rely on it while analysing a position in game.

I really liked the last game I played, so I want to share my analysis of the game. Please share your thoughts and tell me if I went wrong with my moves or my analysis.

```
[FEN ""]

 1. e4 {[%clk 0:15:08]} 1... c6 {[%clk 0:15:08.4]} 2. d4 {[%clk 0:15:14.5]} 2...d5 {[%clk 0:15:16.3]} 3. e5 { [%clk0:15:22.5]} 3... Bf5 [%clk 0:15:18.3]} 4.Bd3 {[%clk 0:15:27.9] a very common reply at my rating level, trying to dispute the diagonal right away. This move allows me to offer a queenless middlegame} 4... Bxd3 {[%clk 0:15:25.6]} 5. Qxd3 {[%clk 0:15:34.3]} 5... Qa5+ {[%clk 0:15:33.1]} 6. Bd2 {[%clk 0:15:34.2]} 6... Qa6 {[%clk 0:15:41.5]} 7. Qxa6 {[%clk 0:15:37.3]} 7... Nxa6 {[%clk 0:15:51.4] from this point on I try to develop, castle kingside and target his d4 pawn} 8. c3 {[%clk 0:15:44.4]} 8... e6 {[%clk 0:15:55.2] a standard developing move to develop both knight and bishop} 9. Nf3 {[%clk 0:15:50.5]} 9... Ne7 {[%clk 0:15:41.2]} 10. Nh4 {[%clk 0:15:51.4] a move I dislike. His intention is to stop 10. Nf5 however after my c5 pawn break I can develop my knight to c6 leaving his h4 knight misplaced} 10... c5 {[%clk 0:15:28.3]} 11. O-O {[%clk 0:15:46.2]} 11... cxd4 {[%clk 0:15:35.2]} 12. cxd4 {[%clk 0:15:51.6] d4 is now a backwards pawn and a structural weakness. The Advance Variation of the Caro-Kann is characterised by the "war over the d4 pawn"} 12... Nc6 {[%clk 0:15:39.3] attacking d4 right away, and because he has to defend d4 this comes with a tempo} 13. Be3 {[%clk 0:15:55.1] better to defend d4 via Nf3} 13... Be7 {[%clk 0:15:19.8] developing the bishop with tempo} 14. Nf3 {[%clk 0:16:00.1]} 14... Nab4 {[%clk 0:15:05.4] improving the position of the knight, threatening Nc2 forking bishop and rook, winning the rook} 15. a3 {[%clk 0:15:51.2]} 15... Nc2 {[%clk 0:15:13.1]} 16. Ra2 {[%clk 0:15:57.7]} 16... Nxe3 {[%clk 0:15:15.2] leaving him with doubled pawns and three pawn islands} 17. fxe3 {[%clk 0:16:03.3]} 17... O-O {[%clk 0:15:18.7]} 18. Nc3 {[%clk 0:15:59.4]} 18... a6 {[%clk 0:14:28.5] stopping Nb5} 19. b4 {[%clk 0:15:56.4]} 19... Rac8 {[%clk 0:14:00.6] better would've been b5 to make Na4 impossible} 20. Na4 {[%clk 0:16:03.1]} 20... b5 {[%clk 0:12:50.3]} 21. Nc5 {[%clk 0:16:08.1] invading via b6 seems better but I think he feared having his knight trapped} 21... Bxc5 {[%clk 0:12:51] because all his pawns are on dark squares I happily trade my bad bishop for his good knight} 22. dxc5 {[%clk 0:16:12.5] this leaves him with double isolated pawns, I prefer bxc5} 22... a5 {[%clk 0:12:01.4]} 23. Rb1 {[%clk 0:16:16]} 23... axb4 {[%clk 0:12:06.6] Ra8 first would've been better} 24. axb4 {[%clk 0:16:21.8]} 24... Ra8 {[%clk 0:12:11.5] contesting the only open file, planning on doubling rooks if he refuses to trade} 25. Rab2 {[%clk 0:16:24.8] a mistake because it lets me double rooks with a tempo and gives me control over the only open file} 25... Ra3 {[%clk 0:11:47.5] attacking e3} 26. Kf2 {[%clk 0:16:29.7]} 26... Rfa8 {[%clk 0:11:48.5]} 27. Kg3 {[%clk 0:16:31.7] a mistake, leaving e3 unprotected} 27... Rxe3 {[%clk 0:11:35.8]} 28. Kf4 {[%clk 0:16:35.8]} 28... Re4+ {[%clk 0:11:09.7] positioning my pieces to attack the weak backwards b4 pawn} 29. Kg3 {[%clk 0:16:42.1]} 29... Ra4 {[%clk 0:10:58.1] Nxe4 comes to mind but I prefer to leave his passed pawn blockaded} 30. Nd2 {[%clk :16:35.6]} 30... Rexb4 {[%clk 0:10:43.8]} 31. Rxb4 {[%clk 0:16:41.9]} 31... Rxb4 {[%clk 0:10:44.7]} 32. Rxb4 {[%clk 0:16:47]} 32... Nxb4 {[%clk 0:10:54.6] a winning position for me being up 2 pawns, both of them passed pawns} 33. Nb3 {[%clk 0:16:51]} 33... Kf8 {[%clk 0:10:54.1]} 34. Kf3 {[%clk 0:16:56.6]} 34... Ke7 {[%clk 0:11:03.1]} 35. Ke3 {[%clk 0:17:01.8]} 35... Kd7 {[%clk 0:11:12.5]} 36. Kd4 {[%clk 0:17:07.5]} 36... Kc6 {[%clk 0:11:07.1] a waste of time on my part, Nc6 wouldve been better} 37. Na5+ {[%clk :17:12.3]} 37... Kc7 {[%clk 0:10:55.4]} 38. Kc3 {[%clk 0:16:52.6]} 38... Nc6 {[%clk 0:10:52.2] offerig a trade, attacking his e-pawn and even more importantly controlling e4, d4, c4, b4, and a4 holding his king at bay} 39. Nb3 {[%clk 0:16:29.9]} 39... b4+ {[%clk 0:09:37.9] not taking on e5 right away because this allows Kb4, notice how this pawn move further drives the king back and at the same time makes it possible to invade with my king via b7-a6-b5-c4} 40. Kd3 {[%clk 0:16:27.1]} 40... Nxe5+ {[%clk 0:09:34.8]} 41. Kd4 {[%clk 0:16:34.2]} 41... Nc6+ {[%clk 0:09:30.2]} 42. Kd3 {[%clk 0:16:39.9]} 42... Kb7 {[%clk 0:09:23.1] with his king cut off from my position i started improving my own king position} 43. Kc2 {[%clk 0:16:40.3]} 43... Ka6 {[%clk 0:09:25]} 44. Kd2 {[%clk 0:16:40.1]} 44... Kb5 {[%clk 0:09:32.7]} 45. Kd3 {[%clk 0:16:46.3]} 45... e5 {[%clk 0:09:12.4] a useful waiting move and taking more space} 46. h3 {[%clk 0:16:49.6]} 46... e4+ {[%clk 0:09:00.8] forcing the king backwards, allowing my king to invade} 47. Kc2 {[%clk 0:16:55.4]} 47... Kc4 {[%clk 0:09:07.5]} 48. Kb2 {[%clk 0:16:57.3]} 48... d4 {[%clk 0:08:55.2]} 49. Nd2+ {[%clk 0:16:54.7]} 49... Kd5 {[%clk 0:08:45.9] not taking c5 right away to stop Nxe4} 50. Nb3 {[%clk 0:16:59.9]} 50... e3 {[%clk 0:08:44.2] threatening to march the epawn up the board} 51. Kc1 {[%clk 0:16:53.4] trying to stop the pawn, this leaves his knight unprotected} 51... Kc4 {[%clk 0:08:44.9]} 52. Na1 {[%clk 0:16:54.9]} 52... Kxc5 {[%clk 0:08:42.2] just now taking the pawn to free my knight} 53. Kc2 {[%clk 0:17:02.6]} 53... Kc4 {[%clk 0:08:51.2] taking the opposition stopping complications via 54. Kd3} 54. g4 {[%clk 0:17:02.4]} 54... d3+ {[%clk 0:08:46.1]} 55. Kd1 {[%clk 0:17:09.1]} 55... b3 {[%clk 0:08:41.8]} 0-1
```

Comment: Sorry about that,  let me just fix it

Comment: Yeah sure thank you for that

Comment: I just realized that there really is no question in there. you might want to re-word it, and ask something specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, a very good game. Here are my thoughts on it.

```
 [FEN ""]

 1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. e5 Bf5 4. Bd3 (4. Nf3 {And Be2 was a line that Nigel Short popularized.}) 4... Bxd3 5. Qxd3 Qa5+ {I think that Capablanca was the first to play this Qa5-a6 idea.} 6. Bd2 Qa6 7. Qxa6 Nxa6 8. c3 e6 9. Nf3 Ne7 10. Nh4 $2 {This puts the knight offside, and the Ne7 may actually go to c6 anyway after c5 is played.} c5 11. O-O cxd4 $2 {Why release the tension, and give his Nb1 a decent square? In addition, you would normally be playing for a minority attack here. After the Na6 is repositioned, and the Be7 is developed, and the Rh8 is brought to c8, the idea would be b5-b4 (maybe with a5, if necessary). This would weakened the white queenside.} (11... Nc6 12. Nf3 (12. Be3 b5 13. Nd2 c4 14. a4 b4 15. f4 {Trying for f5, and his own minority attack.} Be7 16. Nhf3 Rb8 {And black is ready to open the b-file whenever he is ready.}) 12... Kd7 $1 {With the idea of Be7 and Rhc8.} 13. Ng5 cxd4 14. Nxf7 Rg8 15. cxd4 Nxd4 $17 {With a significant advantage.}) 12. cxd4 Nc6 13. Be3 Be7 14. Nf3 Nab4 $6 {Again, finish developing. This does not threaten anything after the natural Nc3.} 15. a3 $2 (15. Nc3 Nc2 16. Rac1 Nxe3 17. fxe3 {Is close to equal.}) 15... Nc2 16. Ra2 Nxe3 $2 {The Be3 was a horrible piece, so I would not have been in a hurry to trade it off. Also e3 although doubled, it is easier to defend than d4 was. A pawn that is closer to home is easier to defend.} (16... Kd7 {Again develop.}) (16... Na5 $5 17. b4 $2 (17. Nbd2 $1 $15) 17...Nxe3 18. fxe3 Nc4 $17 {With a great square for the knight.} 19. Kf2 Kd7 20. Nbd2 b5 {And if white ever takes, you get a strong passer.} 21. Nxc4 $2 bxc4 {And then Rhb8 and a5 will destroy the white queenside.}) 17. fxe3 O-O 18. Nc3 a6 $2 {Taking the c-file, and playing Na5-c4 should have be a priority. Nb5 was not a threat, thus, a6 is unnecessary.} 19. b4 Rac8 {This move was fine, but it was the next that was not great.} 20. Na4 b5 $2 (20... Na7 $1 {This computer move is very hard-to-find, but is borne out of the necessity to be able to defend a6, and then play b6, driving the strong knight out of c5. Hard-to-find, but very logical with some deep thought.} 21. Nc5 Rc7 22. Rb1 Ra8 $1 23. Ne1 Nb5 24. Rb3 b6 25. Na4 Rb8 {And finally black is free of that monster Nc5, and can break with f6!}) 21. Nc5 {Nb6 was not even a consideration here. Not only might it get trapped, but you want squares that have strong bases (pawn protectors) for knights.} Bxc5 {Your bishop is not bad there, but the Nc5 was too strong to let sit there.} 22. dxc5 $2 {This leaves e5 very weak, and thus, limits the mobility of the Nf3.} (22. bxc5 {Of course, this was better.}) 22... a5 $2 {This gives white an opportunity to improve the Nf3.} (22... Ra8 23. Rb1 Rfb8 {Preparing a5.}) 23. Rb1 (23. Nd4 $1 Nxe5 24. Rb1 Rb8 25. bxa5 {With counterplay as the queenside is too open now.}) 23... axb4 24. axb4 Ra8 25. Rab2 $2 Ra3 (25... Rfb8 {Again, thinking about white's idea of Nd4, improving the position...Now, Nd4 just loses a pawn, and you can play Ra4 next, then bring the king up.}) 26. Kf2 $2 (26. Nd4 $1 {Is much better.} Nxd4 (26... Nxe5 $4 {Of course, not this.} 27. Nxb5 Rxe3 28. Rc2 $18 {And the pawns roll.}) 27. exd4 Rfa8 {And bring the king over to c6 and then use the doubled rooks.}) 26... Rfa8 27. Kg3 $4 {This is the final straw.} (27. Nd4 Nxd4 28. exd4 Rd3 $17) 27... Rxe3 28. Kf4 Re4+ 29. Kg3 Ra4 $1 {Excellent...increase the pressure rather than take on e5...e5 will eventually drop. It is indefensible. You also have all the time in the world, so you can bring the king up too to make sure that c5 never becomes a threat. Plus maybe with h6 thrown in to stop Ng5.} 30. Nd2 {This just hastens the defeat.} Rexb4 31. Rxb4 Rxb4 32. Rxb4 Nxb4 33. Nb3 Kf8 $2 {This is not a mistake in that it throws away the win, but you have a tendency to not look at your opponent's ideas. Nd4-b5 was clearly a threat so prevent it.} (33... Nc6 $1 {Of course. This prevents Nd4, but also ties him to e5 too.} 34. Kf4 Kf8 {Now bring the king in.}) 34. Kf3 $2 (34. Nd4 Na6 35. Nxb5 (35. c6 b4 $19) 35... Nxc5 $19) 34... Ke7 (34... Nc6 {Again.}) 35. Ke3 Kd7 36. Kd4 Kc6 (36... Nc6+ $1 37. Kc3 b4+ 38. Kc2 Nxe5 $19) 37. Na5+ Kc7 38. Kc3 Nc6 39. Nb3 b4+ 40. Kd3 Nxe5+ 41. Kd4 Nc6+ 42. Kd3 Kb7 43. Kc2 Ka6 44. Kd2 Kb5 45. Kd3 e5 46. h3 e4+ 47. Kc2 Kc4 48. Kb2 d4 49. Nd2+ Kd5 50. Nb3 e3 51. Kc1 Kc4 52. Na1 Kxc5 {Push the pawns. It does not matter here, but pushing should be your instinct.} (52... d3 $1) 53. Kc2 Kc4 54. g4 d3+ 55. Kd1 b3 0-1
```